# How do I find which list has n numbers of values greater than x in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a list containing multiple members (`list1`). Each member in the list contains various numbers. I want to find the list member(s) that have at least 3 values greater than or equal to 5. How can I accomplish this?

```
aa <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
bb <- c(5,6,9,7,8)
cc <- c(3,8,5,1,6)

list1 <- list(aa,bb,cc)
```

In this case, I'd like to see `bb` and `cc` be returned. Thanks!

Comment: `list1` isn't a named list, is that intentional?

Comment: That was not intentional. My list is actually a named list. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just want the index of the elements that satisfy your condition, use:

```
which(sapply(list1,function(x)sum(x>=5))>=3)
```

if you want the names of the list elements that match your condition, use:

```
names(list1)[sapply(list1,function(x)sum(x>=5))>=3]
```

Comment: Thanks! I accepted this answer because it is the solution to my question as stated. mnel's answer was the solution to the question I meant to ask. I will need this for another part of my code though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Filter` to return a filtered object

```
Filter(function(x) sum(x>=5)>=3,list1)
```

Or if you want a "hadley" solution

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/purrr")
list1 %>% keep(function(x) sum(x>=5)>=3)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I didn't accept this answer because when I posed the question, I just wanted to get the names of the elements. I was then going to use that to try to extract the data. I didn't know this was even possible. Please excuse my ignorance.